# WPF Listbox Wrapping

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, wrappanel

I have a listbox in which I use a ListBox.ItemsPanel - WrapPanel.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Applets}" Margin="10,92,10,10" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True">

                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>



        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>...
```

I am trying to have the wrappanel have a behavior such that the items fill in to the right as the width is made wider and wrap as needed when the window is made narrower.  I have played with it but the correct combination eludes me.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

My next goal would be able to reorder/ sort the items and have the render update.

TIA

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I am trying to have the wrappanel have a behavior such that the items fill in to the right as the width is made wider and wrap as needed when the window is made narrower. I have played with it but the correct combination eludes me. Does anyone have a suggestion?

The code you have is almost correct, just change the `Orientation` to `Horizontal` and it should work as you describe

> My next goal would be able to reorder/ sort the items and have the render update.

You don't have to do anything special for that, it's the normal behavior of a `ListBox`. Just change the sort order (using `ICollectionView.SortDescriptions`), and the UI will reflect the changes

Comment: Oh yes - it works.  Thanks so much.  I must say in general... this is one of the most helpful site.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBoxItem Name="lbiTmp3_1"><CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        lkjfd gmlkdsfmlk gmdsgf  kds lkjglfdjmlkg jfdsg dsgf lkhfdgs lkjds fg
                    </TextBlock></CheckBox>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="lbiTmp3_2">C0ucou</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="lbiTmp3_3">C0ucou</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
```