# Listbox or Listview or Gridview?

Tags: wpf, telerik

I am trying to achieve this.

[image]

I have a list of records (filenames) which I want to show in a list. 
Anybody has any idea as to which control to use.

Regards,
Deepak

Comment: Why wont you search each of that. On that case, you can try to choose by yourself which is the best. And also even other list you havent chosen, atleast you know them (personally). Just a suggestion. Cheers!

Comment: @Niang Thanks for your reply. Actually the issue is I have a long list of records (with only one column) and I want to show it as shown in the image (multicolumn view). The controls I have specified all show data in tabular format and not exactly the way I want. So is there any way/control which can help me achieve that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Listbox Wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139580/wpf-listbox-wrapping)

Answer (score 0):

The information is right at your fingertips. You should learn to use Snoop.  Aside from that, you should choose whatever control works best for you, which requires you to learn the difference between each.  We can't really provide a good answer because there are many different ways this control could be implemented, and that's why WPF is so powerful.

Basically, you'll want to use a mixture of a `Grid` and `ItemsControl`.  You can see the layout of the controls that are being used in this screenshot:

[image]